# matrix multiplication of the form (UP) X = B

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have sudden confusion in matrix multiplication:
If I have
(UP)X = B, where U and P are matrix and B is a vector,
can I write  UX= P^-1 B?
Sorry for asking such a basic question. I got this confusion suddenly before , and I presently donot have resources to confirm this.
Thank you for great help.

Comment: Multiple problems: 1) matrix multiplication is not commutative. 2) $P$ has to be square and even then there is no guarantee that it has an inverse. So the answer is: no, you can, in general not write this.

Comment: Consider P-1 is possible and U is a unitary matrix, then? @Student

Comment: Still no guarantee that the product is commutative.

Comment: Thank you @Student for great and kind help.